# PointerUp в EventTrigger не срабатывает, при одновременном отпускании 2-х кнопок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток,

Делаю игру в жанре гонок и сначала создал управление под клавиатуру, но потом понадобилось добавить возможность игры на мобильных устройствах и я реализовал это через EventTrigger с методами PointerDown и PointerUp

Вот пример кода функций, которые вызывают события PointerDown/Up (TurnLeft/RightButtonDown/Up просто меняют булевое значение в другом скрипте):

```
public void TurnLeftButtonDown()
{
    currentCar.TurnLeftButtonDown();
}

public void TurnLeftButtonUp()
{
    currentCar.TurnLeftButtonUp();
}

public void TurnRightButtonDown()
{
    currentCar.TurnRightButtonDown();
}

public void TurnRightButtonUp()
{
    currentCar.TurnRightButtonUp();
}
```

Вот инспектор одной педали, везде сделано так же

[image: Инспектор педали]

Проблема появилась, когда тестировал игру на Яндекс играх на мобильном устройстве. При одновременном "отпускании" 2х кнопок 1 из них не считывает этого "отпускания" и остаётся как бы зажатой пока не нажать и не отпустить её ещё раз.

Изначально думал что это из-за того, что я оставил компонент Button (onClic пустой, но даёт анимацию нажатия на педаль), но после отключения компонента проблема осталась. (Пока я не отключил Button, было видно что залипшая педаль была в анимации "зажатия", будто бы палец на ней)

Помогите плиз, и на ютубе и в ассетах всё работает по той же схеме, поэтому я даже не знаю в какую сторону совершать телодвижения

Заранее спасибо!